# How to Search records using Node js Mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongoose

i am begineer of node js and mongo db i need to search the records.it is displayed as black i saw the console i attached the output below.what i receieve the output below i attached.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Mlrb.jpg)

please check them.what i tried so far i attached below.

**routes**

`router.route('/user/findOne').get(userController.findOneUserController);`

**userController.js
**

```
var findOneUserController = async (req, res) => 
{
   
   console.log(req.params.name);
var result = await userService.findOneUserDBService(req.params.name);


    if (result) {
        res.send({ "status": true, "data": result} );
    } else {
        res.send({ "status": false, "data": "User not found" });
    }
}
```

**userModel **

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var userSchema = new Schema({

    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    address: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    phone: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    }
   

});

module.exports = mongoose.model('employees', userSchema);
```

**userServices.js
**

```
module.exports.findOneUserDBService = (userDetais) => {


    return new Promise(function myFn(resolve, reject) {
 
        userModel.findOne(userDetais, function returnData(error, result) {
 
          if(error)
          {
                reject(false);
          }
          else
          {
             resolve(result);
          }
 
           
        });
 
    });
 
 }
```

Comment: We don't know what is the value of `req.query`

Comment: just get the request i put .if it wrong please help me write good way to search using param

Comment: i changed those as console.log(req.params.name);
    var result = await userService.findOneUserDBService(req.params.name); but output undefined

Comment: if want to query by name use below example as reference :-
const user = await User.findOne({name:userDetails })
where , User=UserModel , userDetails = req.params.name

Comment: i checked through on post man http://localhost:3000/user/findOne/John but not working

Comment: you have not passed params name that why params might be undefined use:
router.get('/user/findOne/:name',userController.findOneUserController)

Comment: can you write the full code

Comment: try to console.log(req.params) once you will be it , when you hit api in postman

Comment: you want code for just querying user by name right ?

Comment: yes sir ...........................